# Загрузка картинки в WP через php

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю скрипт, который будет загружать картинку в библиотеку медиафайлов. Движок WordPress, но скрипт(самопис), который выполняет загрузку, к движку никакого отношения не имеет.

Я выполняю загрузку картинки, кладу её в папку `/wp-content/uploads/`.

Далее делаю запись в таблицах: `wp_posts` и в `wp_postmeta`.

В таблицу `wp_posts` записываю имя картинки, то, что это attachment и image/jpeg, - в общем, все то, что присуще картинки (подсмотрел у записи, которую создал сам WordPress при загрузке через админку).

В таблицу `wp_postmeta` добавляю запись с новым **post_id**, _wp_attached_file, photo.jpg.

В итоге получается, что картинка на сервере есть, но в медиатеке она отображается без миниатюры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добавлять attachments нужно через спец. функцию `wp_insert_attachment`. Если добавлять без нее, то WP не нарежет миниатюры сам и тогда не будет превью картинки, как у вас на скрине. Пример загрузки картинок:

```
$image_url = 'adress img';

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );

$filename = basename( $image_url );

if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
  $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
}
else {
  $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

$attachment = array(
  'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
  'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: а какие нужно подключить скрипты для этого? чтобы понимали - у меня чистый php скрипт, в котором нет никаких "инклудов" от wp

Comment: require_once '../../../wp-load.php';

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ. А автору вопроса совет - перестаньте лазить в базу руками. Вы обязательно что-нибудь сломаете, как и вышло у вас в вопросе. На всё есть функции WordPress.

Comment: Хороший ответ, плюсанул. Но я бы ещё добавил что без этого (так, как делает ТС) вложения не будут корректны в медиатеке + возможны разные проблемы, если писать в базу в обход АПИ.